# How to code a simple sync REST API to check if a file exist in the server with node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I need to code a REST API that can check if a PDF file exist in a specific folder in the server.

The client send GET request and server should wait before send response, until the PDF file exist.

When the PDF file appears in the folder, the server need to response filename to client.

I think using node.js with express and socket.io to do this.

Do you think it's the right way ?

Have you got a code example for sync wait and file check response ?

Thanks

Before coding REST API routes, i prefer in a first step to code file checking function.

I tested fs.existsSync not really good

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const path = './*.pdf'
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    //file exists
}
```

and i am going to test maybe with [glob.sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) or [glob-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-fs)

I don't know what the good way for this first step

Update :

Glob-fs seems to be ok, but I need a wait time until .PDF file arrived on the server fs.

```js
var glob = require('glob-fs')({ gitignore: true });

glob.readdir('**/*.pdf', function(err, files) {
  console.log(files);
});
```

Comment: Using REST and Websockets (socket.io) are going to be two different concepts. If you want to make a GET request and wait for the file to exist to send the response (a bad idea), I'm not sure why Websockets would be required. It's more of an either/or thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST API is not what you are looking for. You should not stall your node.js server.

You should use Websocket: You can register your application as interested to know when a file appears in a directory. Then, when that event occurs, the server sends you a notification. No waiting.

Check https://www.tutorialspoint.com/websockets/index.htm for more info about Websockets.

Check https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener for watching file modifications

Comment: Actually, this operation seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.
I'll look at the websockets side instead of the REST APIs and fs.watch instead of Glob. Thank you for the tracks :-)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Here a code using [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) to watch PDF file creation :

```
var fileWatcher = require("chokidar");

// Initialize watcher.
var watcher = fileWatcher.watch("./*.pdf", {
    ignored: /[\/\\]\./,
    persistent: true
});

// Add event listeners.
watcher
    .on('add', function(path) {
        console.log('File', path, 'has been added');
    })
```